# Using RestTemplateBuilder with @ContextConfiguration in IT tests

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, resttemplate, spring-test, context-configuration

I am running into problems while using RestTemplateBuilder with @ContextConfiguration in a Spring boot application (I have tried to add @SpringBootTest, @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) annotation without any luck).

Any help is appreciated. Here is the background:

I have annotated my class like the following:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    JsonNodeList.class,
    JsonNodeUtils.class,
    MyService.class,
    RestClient.class,
    RestTemplateBuilder.class}, loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class)
 public class StepsDefinition {
```

The RestClient class has RestTemplateBuilder autowired as:

```
 @Autowired
  public RestClient(final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    this.restTemplate = configureRestTemplate(restTemplateBuilder);
  }
```

MyService class autowires the RestClient. When i try to load the application using `@ContextConfiguration` with `SpringBootContextLoader`, i am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplateBuilder': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.<init>()
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by using `@SpringBootTest` and adding `RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class` to the classes array:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyTest {
   // test methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when attempting to run unit tests.  Here are the annotations that are working for me:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { RestTemplate.class })
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigurationPackage
public class MyTest {
   // test methods
}
```

When I had the `RestTemplateBuilder.class` specified in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { RestTemplate.class, RestTemplateBuilder.class })
```

I got the same exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplateBuilder': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.<init>()
```